# Objective-C API: Can an NSNumber become an Int in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, api-design

I am writing a framework in Objective-C, and the goal is it should be a joy to use in Swift as well.

One of my properties is a nullable NSNumber. Is there any way to bridge this to an optional Int when the API is used in Swift?

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation:

> Swift automatically bridges certain native number types, such as Int
>   and Float, to NSNumber.
>
> It also allows you to pass a value of type Int, for example, to an
>   argument expecting an NSNumber. Note that because NSNumber can contain
>   a variety of different types, you cannot pass it to something
>   expecting an Int value.
>
> All of the following types are automatically bridged to NSNumber:
>
> - Int
> - UInt
> - Float
> - Double
> - Bool

So you can safely use these scalar types in swift and cast them to `NSNumber` in objc, but not the other way around. `NSNumber` may represent a float value, and you will see an error if you cast it to `Int` in swift.

Comment: Right, I was hoping there was a way to "promise" an Int NSNumber so that there would be a bridging …

Comment: You could you `NSInteger` which is automatically bridged to swift as `Int`.

Comment: But I don't see the problem of using a NSNumber in Swift. Just calling integerValue will return its value converted to Int